# Getting errors while trying to install packages using npm

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

When i try to install any package with npm or just  npm install i get a list of errors 
Have no idea on what to do

```
C:\Users\Dhayalan\Documents\app>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Dhayalan\Documents\app\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Dhayalan\Documents\app
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dhayalan\Documents\app\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dhayalan\Documents\app\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\Dhayalan\Documents\app>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your packages does not have a `package.json` file. There are two cases where this error might occur:

- `npm install`: Installs all packages defined in `package.json`.
- `npm install packagename --save` Installs package and adds it as an dependency to `package.json`.

Doing just `npm install packagename` should always work fine. You can create a `package.json` by running `npm init`.